# remove/update document field on elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Imagine a class as:

```
class DummyClass
{
    String field1;
    String field2;
}
```

I'm able to create an `DummyClass` object and save it on ES:

```
DummyClass dummy = new DummyClass();
dummy.field1 = "sample1";
dummy.field2 = "sample2";

byte[] source = this.jacksonMapper.writeValueAsBytes(dummy);
this.elasticsearchResources.getElasticsearchClient()
    .prepareIndex()
    .setIndex("index")
    .setType("type")
    .setSource(source)
    .request();
```

`source`'s content is:

```
{
    "field1": "sample1",
    "field2": "sample2"
}
```

So, I need to do a change like: `dummy.field1 = null`, so I need `field1` is deleted (I don't want ES set `field1 = null`).

So, I've tried this:

```
 dummy.field1 = null;

 byte[] source = this.jacksonMapper.writeValueAsBytes(dummy);

 this.elasticsearchResources.getElasticsearchClient()
        .prepareUpdate()
        .setIndex("index")
        .setType(type)
        .setId(id.toString())
        .setDoc(source)
        .setUpsert(source)
        .setDetectNoop(true)
        .request();
```

`source`'s content is:

```
{
    "field2": "sample2"
}
```

After that, ES doesn't delete `field1` from document.
I'm not quite able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the source in the second example looks like this?
Elasticsearch replaces the whole document with the new Json provided. It doesn't do any updates so it means your sending json with field1 = null

Answer (score 3):

UpdateRequest only do merge or partial update if you are using java SDK. In order to do replacement, please use IndexRequest, if document already exist, it overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, ElasticSearch replaces the document if you index again. Following should do what you want:

```
PUT idx/tpy/1
{"name1" : "value1", "name2" : "value2"}

POST idx/tpy/_search
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}

PUT idx/tpy/1
{"name1" : "value1"}

POST idx/tpy/_search
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
```

Comment: As far I've been able to figure out, Update API tries to MERGE the document (see on [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update.html)). In order to remove the field, you should to provide an script... What do you think about?

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing it is, if you are using setter methods to set class variables and then convert it to map to write into ES. In this case which ever fields has null value will be omitted from writing to ES

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class DummyClass
{
    String field1;
    String field2;
}
```

If you already hav a null field in ES, what you could do is, get the document 1 by 1  as a map

```
Map<String, Object> fieldMap = getFields.getSourceAsMap();
```

now remove the field you got to delete from the Map, ex., `fieldMap.remove("field1");`

Now re-index this new Map.

```
 IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder = esClient.createDocument(INDEXName, INDEXTYPE, docid , fieldMap);
```